# Making of the World Wonders 3D Globe: whole earth

Tags: three.js, webgl

Stating from this excellent article ([Making of the World Wonders 3D Globe](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/globe/?ModPagespeed=noscript)), I try to replace the demo markers with my own markers, with success.

But I want to render the whole earth in the window, not only the top (about 30%):
[My test page](http://www.mobbum.com/globe/globe.html).

I have not yet all understand about WebGl, so can you help me?

Comment: #abstract-algorithm Finally I've just found that I have to set the distance value in the render() function:
dist=1200;
http://www.mobbum.com/globe/globe1.html

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with this:

```
 camera.position.set(x,y,z); // you custom coordinates
```

The globe is there, you simply need to re-position the camera to suits you. You would probably need to adjust `z` and `y` coordinates, and note that THREE.js uses right-handed coordinate system.

Hope this helps.